# typeahead.js with local data value and display string

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm trying to do a simple select box with a static set of data options.

```
  <input type="text" id="qs-city-select" name="city" class="typeahead tt-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type a city">
```

My jquery code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var numbers = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: [
 { "value": "21", "name": "Twenty one" },
 { "value": "22", "name": "Twenty two" },
]
});

numbers.initialize();

$('#qs-city-select').typeahead({hint: false}, {
displayKey: 'value',
source: numbers.ttAdapter()
});

});
```

I want the visible options to select to be "twenty one" and "twenty two" and then the values of 21 or 22 to be passed via the form. I can't get this to work. I can only get it to work where it displays and passes as a value the same string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Struggling with this too. Looks like typeahead.js doesn't support this cleanly out of the box, unbelievably. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Because typeahead piggy backs on a html input node I believe it will always set the value of that input to the value of what is shown to the user. You could change the typeahead js and possibly script around this functionality, or what I would do is bind to the "select" event of the typeahead and set the value of another hidden html input.

This is how:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name + " " + d.value); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [
        { "value": "21", "name": "Twenty one" },
        { "value": "22", "name": "Twenty two" },
    ]
});

numbers.initialize();

var a = $('#qs-city-select').typeahead({hint: false}, {
    displayKey: 'name', //displays the name value of the datum to the end user eg. "Twenty one"
    source: numbers.ttAdapter()
});

$('#qs-city-select').bind('typeahead:select', function(e, datum) {
  $('#qs-city-select').typeahead('val', datum.name); //Use the typeahead api to override default behaviour of setting the typeaheads value to the datums value ie from "21" to "Twenty one"
  $('#hidden-input').val(datum.value); //set the hidden inputs value to the datum value eg. "21"
  console.log($('#hidden-input').val());
});
```

});

Here's a working js [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rel/jyu4gLLq/3/):

Side Note: Depending on what you want your users string to match on you can change

```
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name) //match on "Twenty one" etc
```

to

```
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value) //match on 21, 22 etc
```

or match on both

```
return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name + " " + d.value) //match on"Twenty one" or "21"
```

Comment: Won't this show the 'hidden' value in the input box to the user once it's selected?